# How to detect hidden text in pdf

Tags: pdf, text, extract

We are extracting text from PDF using iText/PDFBox, but additional text, invisible in the PDF, also gets extracted.  Is there any any method and/or tools to get rid of these hidden texts?

Comment: show some sample for hidden text?where is the code?

Comment: It's a straight parsing of pdf content stream where the hidden text is extracted along with normal text.The text covered by image or any  vector drawings also comes out in this way because there seems to be no way of detecting if any object is covered over by another.

Comment: i have the same problem. i sometimes need to "censor" texts, so i cover areas with rectangles. then i print as pdf, so the rectangles arent mere annotations any more. but it's still possible to select and copy the stuff under the rectangles. right now i resort to converting to images afterwards, but thats not elegant.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to add hidden text including

1. Hidden on an hidden / invisible / locked content group layer
2. White text colour on an OCG
3. 100% transparent text
4. ???

Each PDF may use a different method and to be able to separate them it you may need to know how the hidden text is implemented.

Does iText have an option to return the text colour ?  If it does then you can try ignoring white coloured text objects.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! But here I was looking more for the case where text is covered over by some image or vector drawings.Is there some tool to remove such content ?

Comment: You would need to extract both logos and text from the PDF and then perform a check to see if an image is underneath a logo.  You then open a whole can of worms with transparent images where there may be text visible on the PDF but the test is technically under an image.  Another option would be to check the text color or transparency of the text objects to see if they a draw or not.  The are many different ways to draw/hide text and you would need a tool that knows all the different tricks.  If your PDF's all come from one source then you will have a much better chance.  OCR is another option